# RxJava и Retrofit. Автоматическое обновление данных из сети

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rxjava, rxandroid

Всем привет! 
Мне нужно при запуске приложения получить данные из БД и отобразить их на экране.Соответственно при изменении данных в БД поменять их и на экране(С этим я справился). Так же параллельно нужно взять данные из БД и для каждого элемента из списка сделать запрос в сеть и при удачном запросе обновить эти данные в БД. В принципе, это я тоже реализовал, но проблема в том, что запросы в сеть идут постоянно, пока работает приложение, а мне нужен только один запрос для каждого элемента, т.к. лимит запросов у API ограничен.
Вот код:
Вызовы из Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mCitiesListPresenter.subscribe(this);
    mCitiesListPresenter.loadDBData();//получение данных из БД
    mCitiesListPresenter.loadNetData();//обновление данных из сети

}
```

Реализация в презентере:

```
public void loadDBData(){
    getDataFromDB();
}

public void loadNetData(){
    getDataFromApi();
}

private void getDataFromDB(){
    getView().showProgress();
    Disposable disposable = mModel.getCities()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::updateUI
                    ,this::handleError);

    mCompositeDisposable.add(disposable);
}

private void getDataFromApi(){
    getView().showProgress();

    Disposable disposable = mModel.getCities()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(this::getStringCitiesName)//трансформируем в String[]
            .flatMap(Observable::fromArray)//создаем Observable для каждого элемента
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::queryAPI);

    mCompositeDisposable.add(disposable);
}

private void queryAPI(String s) {

    Disposable disposable = mModel.getWeatherWithCityName(s)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::updateCityInDB
                    ,throwable -> {
                        Log.d(Utils.APP_TAG, "getDataFromApi: " + throwable);
                        getView().showToast("Ошибка связи");});

    mCompositeDisposable.add(disposable);
}
```

Возможно решить проблему можно очень просто, но я уже около недели прочесываю просторы интернета и пока не нашел нужного решения. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему у вас `mModel.getCities()` возвращает `Flowable` или `Observable`. Засим происходит вызов `queryAPI` на каждое изменение в БД. Т.е.

1. Получаем список городов.
2. Для первого вызываем запрос в сеть.
3. Обновляем его в БД.
4. Срабатывает цепочка получения городов опять (п1)
5. Опять для первого города идёт запрос в сеть etc.

В итоге да - очень много запросов повторяющихся. Это решается просто - сделайте ещё один метод для получения городов, который будет срабатывать всего раз. Для этого сделайте его `Single`. Что-то типа

```
 public Single<City> getCytiesSingle() { ... }
```

Comment: сделал так, теперь mModel.getCitiesSingle() возвращает Single<List<City>>. Но реализация метода Disposable disposable = mModel.getCitiesSingle()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(this::getStringCitiesName)
                .flatMapObservable(Observable::fromArray)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::queryAPI);    все равно посылает постоянные запросы. Или я что-то не так переделал?

Comment: а нет,разобрался. все работает. Спасибо